# Why cant i place my divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

I'm a complete beginner and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. I want to have my text next to each other, like one on the right side, the other one on the left side.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCFN8EujbGI

I copied most of it from this video. It should look like in 36:50 but the section My education is under the section My experiences. (Dont judge the structure of my code this is my first week).

```
<div class="SectionA1" id="SectionA1">
    <h1> hi </h1>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" > 
        <h2> hi </h2>
        <ul class="timeline" style="height: 425px;">
            <li>
                <h3 style="width: 95px"><span>hi</span></h3><br>
                <p>hi<br>
                <b>hi</b> - hi<br>
                <b>hi</b> - hi<br>
                <b>hi</b> - hi
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3 style="width: 95px"><span>hi</span></h3><br>
                <p>hi<br>
                <b>hi</b> - hi<br>
                <b>hi</b> - hi<br>
                <b>hi</b> - hi
                </p>
            </li>       
        </ul>   
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-6" >
        <h2> hi </h2>
        <ul class="timeline" style="height: 650px;">
            <li>
                <h3 style="width: 95px"><span>hi</span></h3><br>
                <p>hi<br>
                <b>hi</b> - hir<br>
                <b>hi</b> - hi<br>
                <b>hi</b> - hi
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3 style="width: 95px"><span>hi</span></h3><br>
                <p>hi<br>
                <b>hi</b> - hi<br>
                <b>hi</b> - hi <br>
                <b>hi</b> - hi
                </p>
            </li>   
            <li>
                <h3 style="width: 95px"><span>hi</span></h3><br>
                <p>hi<br>
                <b>hi</b> - hif<br>
                <b>hi</b> - hi<br>
                <b>hi</b> - hi
                </p>
            </li>   
        </ul>   
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>  
    </div>


html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

body{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Montserrat;
}

#SectionA1{
    height: 910px;
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000000;
    background: url();
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) !important;
    background-blend-mode: color;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover; 
}

.SectionA1{
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.SectionA1 h2{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: 300px;
}

.SectionA1 li{
    margin-left: 15%;
}

.SectionA1 p{
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 2.2em;
}

.timeline{
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

.timeline:before{
    content:'';
    background: #555;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 160px;
    width: 3px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.timeline li h3{    
    width: 200px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.timeline li h3 span{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ccc
}

.timeline li:before{
    content: '';
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    left: 150px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: You're probably missing brackets `{ }` (and/or semicolons `;`) in your CSS causing your CSS to not work like in the video, and also why you couldn't post the CSS here.  But yes, we would need to see the CSS to help you with this.

Comment: Your CSS (from line 60) is not encapsuleted into a <style> tag. Wrap it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link to the bootstrap. When I added bootstrap from CDN, it works: https://prnt.sc/r9xiv6

Comment: ty ! just curious why does it work with bootstrap? what ist this?

Comment: Bootstrap is an open source toolkit for developing with HTML, CSS, and JS.
In your video watch from 3:25